# how to test MFMessageComposeViewController on iPhone simulator?

Tags: iphone, sms

Is there anyway or I must get a iPhone?
Can I inherit form MFMessageComposeViewController to add some function in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't inherit `MFMessageComposeViewController`, you could present the view controller modally using the `presentModalViewController`, [More](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)